# Ugly font rendering with Android Studio on Java8

Tags: java, fonts, android-studio

I am using Oracle Java 8 and Android Studio, but it is difficult to work with it because of the ugly font rendering. Here are some screen-shots.

[image: code in Android Studio]

[image: more code in Android Studio]

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64-bit. Android Studio is set to use the GTK Themes. I have also added the following options to `andriod-studio/bin/studio64.vmoptions` and `android-studio/bin/studio64.vmoptions` as described in [this post on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/614960/how-to-fix-font-anti-aliasing-in-intellij-idea-when-using-high-dpi).

```
-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on
-Dswing.aatext=true
-Dsun.java2d.xrender=true
```

Apart from the GTK theme settings in **Android-Studio > Settings > Appearance**, nothing else is done.

I am also not really happy with the overall fonts settings on my machine. Here is a screenshot of firefox:

[image: reddit posts]

I have only installed some powerline fonts in my `~/.fonts` directory for my rxvt terminal. That's all.

Any pointers on how to go from here?

Answer (score 4):

IntelliJ and Android Studio have long had issues with font rendering. However a setting for this was added in Android Studio 2.0. It might help

**Appearance and Behaviour > Appearance > Antialiasing**

[image: settings dialog window]

Comment: I tried that too but didn't work out the way it should. I am now using a mac, and thinks work out if the box there.

Comment: I've this problem with Android Studio but not with IntelliJ. The settings are the same... go figure.

Answer (score 4):

In the bundled JRE, there's a font configuration file which seems to default to full hinting.

To change this, open `jre/lib/fonts/font.conf` and locate the following part:

```
<edit mode="assign" name="hintstyle">
  <const>hintfull</const>
</edit>
```

There, replace `hintfull` with [a different hintstyle](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Font_configuration#Hintstyle), e.g. `hintslight` which is usually the default for other UIs in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Quick fix for me: delete the jre directory in your AndroidStudio directory. It will now use your java set with JAVA_HOME. Make sure you have one.